# Getting Eclipse's Progress View

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to capture Eclipse's Progress View? I want to know if the Progress View displays `No operations to display at this time.` or if there is a running progress.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress view id is `org.eclipse.ui.views.ProgressView` and it is implemented by `org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressView`. Since this is an **internal** class it is not part of the Eclipse API and you should not attempt to use it. In any case it does not provide a way to see what is currently being displayed.

You can find out if the job manager is currently idle using:

```java
boolean idle = Job.getJobManager().isIdle();
```

Comment: Hi @greg-449, thank you! Is there a way to put this into some sort of checker? I tried putting it into display.getdefault async but Eclipse is not responding. If I put the checker in a job, it will forever run.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are asking. Ask a new question with more details

Comment: Hi @greg-449, I have created a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 4 now has the ProgressView officially made available, see
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/ProgressView